# How to check if a CheckBox is checked or not without "if statement "?

Tags: c#

So basically I want to set the `label1`'s font to **Bold** if the check box is checked and to **Regular** when it's unchecked but I can't figure out how I can do it without an `if` statement.
this is what I have now with an `if` statement.

```
private void checkBoxBold_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
           if (checkBoxBold.Checked == true)
              label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
           else 
              label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
```

Comment: you can use conditional operator: work in many languages like C#, Java ... ```label1.Font = checkboxBold.Checked ? new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold) : new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);``` you can also move thing even more, get rid of duplicate codes: ```label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, checkBoxBold.Checked?FontStyle.Bold:FontStyle.Regular);```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but isn't it basically the same as `if  else` statement but much cleaner ? is there a way to do it without `if` or `?` ?

Comment: @Bartiya Fatemi that's exactly as you said, internally compiler will treat them the same, but it's cleaner in here. if you want to remove the if statement? you can decrease their number, but not removing it totally. if you are interested, I'll describe in separate answer.

Comment: @deadManN someone asked me this question and said that she did it using event's default objects (or was it the label1 Font objects? can't remember correctly ) and no `if` statement involved anywhere in the code but didn't explain how. would love to learn more about decreasing the number of `if`s too ; much appreciated.

Comment: for that instance I rather like to see the code before say a things.

Comment: @deadManN well I got her answer today and that was kinda a lie that she could do it without an `if` statement . `label1.Font = ((CheckBox)sender).Font;` this is how she did it and well the problem with this is , when you uncheck the checkbox the `FontStyle` won't change to `Regular` ; also you need to set the `CheckBox`'s `FontStyle` to **Bold** at the first place.

Comment: well that's another way, I did that long ago, in collage too. But @John-wu sure come with the right idea, and prove that it is possible; We used to use the same method with styling in `angularjs`, maybe in `angular X` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after thinking and learning new things about C# I came up with a new idea on how I can do this without an `if` statement.
The `sender` sends a `String` that has the `CheckState` of the `Checkbox` declared in it.
The string looks like this :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox, CheckState: 1
```

And well with knowing about the string and `Fontstyle Enums` all I had to do was to get the `CheckState` assigned number which shows if the `Checkbox` is checked or not and use it to set the `label1`'s `Fontstyle`.
well this is how I did it :

```cs
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, ((FontStyle)Convert.ToInt32(sender.ToString().Substring(sender.ToString().Length - 1))));
```

In this case, the `Enum`'s assigned `int` number and the `State` of `Checkbox` are the same, but even if we wanted to set the `label1`'s `Fontstyle` to something else still we could use this way and some math. For example, if we want to set the `Fontstyle` to **Italic** when the `checkbox` is `checked` and to **Regular** when it's unchecked we could simply get the last char of the `sender`'s`string` and put it in `int X`. then we do something like `X=2*X` (the **Italic**'s `int` value is `2`) and the rest is the same as above.
and here is a more clear version of my solution:

```cs
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String str = sender.ToString();
            
            int X = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(str.Length - 1));

            FontStyle fontstylee = ((FontStyle)X);

            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, fontstylee);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
label1.Font = checkBoxBold.Checked ? new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold) : new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Or if you want it to be like what you wrote:

```
label1.Font = (checkBoxBold.Checked == true) ? new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold) : new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
```

If the statement before ? is true it will return the left side of : else it will return the right side.

Or like @deadManN said:

```
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, (checkBoxBold.Checked ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but isn't it basically the same as `if  else` statement but much cleaner ? is there a way to do it without `if` or `?` ? maybe using sender objects or so .

Comment: Yes it's the same. But you have to check it somehow. Sender object is the same with the checkbox that called the event so it's checkbox1 in this example. You need to check the checkbox one way or another. @BardiyaFatemi

Answer (score 1):

Since we're doing things the hard way, how about this?

```
label1.Font = new Font
(
    label1.Font, 
    new Dictionary<bool, FontStyle>
    {
        { true, FontStyle.Bold },
        { false, FontStyble.Regular} 
    }[checkBoxBold.Checked]
);
```

Comment: isn't that harder (need much more processing)? but it sure is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a system with so many if else check, which are bound together and comes in different places, but work toward same state, There is a way to decrease number of `if`s.

For this you can go toward Strategy or State patterns (I hope I'm not wrong about the name of the pattern):

the state is when your state is inside the object you are working with, in strategy you use a system which can be anything.

For example:
Think you have multiple way of writing:
A. Bold with size of 18px and black color with xxx font   - let call it header
B. regular with size of 12px and blue color with yyy font - let call it text
C. Italic with size of 14 and red color with zzz font     - let call it quote

in this case which I know these are fixed, and are defined, and called in different places (which mean multiple `if`s) I would do the following:

First create an interface which define the way of writing:

**Note**: *Font data types are made in my mind and may not be valid*

```
public interface IWriteStyle 
{
     public Style Style { get; }
     public int Size { get; }
     public string FontName { get; }
     public Color Color { get; }
}
```

then you create your writing styles based on this contract / interface:

```
public class HeaderWritingStyle : IWritingStyle {
    public Style Style => Style.Bold;
    public int Size => 18;
    public string FontName => "xxx";
    public Color Color => Color.Black;
}

public class TextWritingStyle : IWritingStyle {
    public Style Style => Style.None;
    public int Size => 12;
    public string FontName => "yyy";
    public Color Color => Color.Blue;
}

public class QuoteWritingStyle : IWritingStyle {
    public Style Style => Style.Italic;
    public int Size => 14;
    public string FontName => "zzz";
    public Color Color => Color.Red;
}
```

now in you system you set the writingStyle in your desired way, or read it from config or shared class, for example, a simple way can be:

```
Class MyApp {
     private IWritingStyle _writingStyle;
     
     public MyApp() 
     {
          SetWritingStyle(new HeaderWritingStyle());
     }

     public void SetWritingStyle(IWritingStyle style){
         this.WritingStyle
     }

....
```

And then you will use it like this:

```
private void On_X_Event(event ...)
{
    ChangeTextColor(writingStyle.Color);
}

private void On_Y-Event(event ...)
{
    ChangeTextSize(writingStyle.Size);
}
```

You can change the Writing style of whole system by changing the writingStyle, and if you need to conditionate it, you will do it once whenever you decide your style.

```
SetWritingStyle( textObj.IsQuote? new QuoteWritingStyle() : new TextWritingStyle() )
```

I know the sample in here is not very practical, as you would like to have all these styles all together or none, there aren't much of system who would want these properties one by one, it's mostly all or nothing. but think about for example a Car, an class that performs several operations, differently per OS, and you create your specific desired object once for that OS, and you start to using it in the application life cycle, without calling a single if afterward.

Comment: Thanks for introducing this strategy to me, learned alot.

Comment: would love to know your opinion on the solution that I came up with and tagged as Answer.